# Tomcat 9.0.17 session replication issue

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I have Tomcat 9.0.17 installed and trying to test session replication. Cluster has 2 nodes on 2 different machines.

Applications are deployed on both the servers individually.

Load balancing is enabled on Round robin way. But the fail-over and session replication is not working as expected.

Could you resolve this issue? Any config files that I can compare and implement in my project to resolve the session replication issue? Since I have never made config changes for session replication, I am not able to resolve this.

Comment: Hi, Update: Fail-over is working fine. But I still have issues with Session replication. When I bring down the active node which is serving the application, session is killed. A new JSESSIONID is created and redirected to the welcome page.

Comment: how you solve this issue we are facing same issue